# sql table design structure - notifications table with multiple types like voucher, comment, followed etc

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database-design, relational-database

I have a table `user_notifications`:

and I have multiple types of notifications like:

- `Deal Notification`
- `Promotion Notification`
- `Followed Notification`
- `Follow Request Notification`
- `Voucher Notification`
- `Post Comment Notification`
- `Tagged Notification`

etc

each `type` of notification, have its own table like: `Deal` have a `Deal Table`, `Promotion` have a `Promotion Table` etc, when the notification is clicked it will link to the data in that table.

Currently I have the main table `user_notifications` to store generic data that ALL `types` share like: `notification_id`, `Created_date`, `Sender_id`, `Receiver_id` etc

and multiple side-tables like: `n_deal`, `n_promotion`, `n_followed` etc

that will be JOINED to `user_notifications`, when retrieving specific type of data

is this the correct table structure design for this case?

Comment: I don't get the n_ prefix for the side_tables

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for a few of them, plus some sample `SELECTs`.  Without seeing what you want to fetch from the tables, we cannot judge whether the schema is 'correct'.

Comment: Search re subtyping in sql database design.